# How do you copy a file in PHP without overwriting an existing file?

Tags: php, file, file-io

When you use the PHP [copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function, the operation blindly copies over the destination file, even if it already exists.  How do you copy a file safely, only performing the copy if there is no existing file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to call [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check to see if the file exists, but doing that could cause a race condition.  There is always the possibility that the other file will be created in between when you call [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and when you call [copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).  The only safe way to check if the file exists is to use [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

When you call [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), set the mode to 'x'.  This tells [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to create the file, but only if it doesn't exist.  If it exists, [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) will fail, and you'll know that you couldn't create the file.  If it succeeds, you will have a created a file at the destination that you can safely copy over.  Sample code is below:

```
// The PHP copy function blindly copies over existing files.  We don't wish
// this to happen, so we have to perform the copy a bit differently.  The
// only safe way to ensure we don't overwrite an existing file is to call
// fopen in create-only mode (mode 'x').  If it succeeds, the file did not
// exist before, and we've successfully created it, meaning we own the
// file.  After that, we can safely copy over our own file.

$filename = 'sourcefile.txt'
$copyname = 'sourcefile_copy.txt'
if ($file = @fopen($copyname, 'x')) {
    // We've successfully created a file, so it's ours.  We'll close
    // our handle.
    if (!@fclose($file)) {
        // There was some problem with our file handle.
        return false;
    }

    // Now we copy over the file we created.
    if (!@copy($filename, $copyname)) {
        // The copy failed, even though we own the file, so we'll clean
        // up by itrying to remove the file and report failure.
        unlink($copyname);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You still have a race condition. But you're on the right track--if the fopen succeeds, use fwrite() to perform the copy, and unlink the source file when complete.

Comment: In addition to what Nathan said, open with an exclusive lock, to prevent writes from other programs during the copy.

Answer (score 3):

I think you answered your own question - check to make sure the destination file exists before performing the copy. If the file exists, skip the copy.

Update: I see you really did answer your own question. You mention race conditions, but if you do find that the file already exists, how do you know that:

- the file that is already there is really the one you want to copy
- the other process copying the file has completed its job (the file data is all there)
- the other process copying the file isn't going to fail (and leave an incomplete file, or delete the new file)

I think you should consider these questions when designing a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A honey badger function, which just doesn't care about race-conditions, but works cross-platform.

```
function safeCopy($src, $dest) {
    if (is_file($dest) === true) {
        // if the destination file already exists, it will NOT be overwritten.        
        return false;
    }

    if (copy($src, $dest) === false) {
        echo "Failed to copy $src... Permissions correct?\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`link()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.link.php) function instead of `copy()`.

```
function safe_copy($src, $dest) {
    if (link($src, $dest)) {
        // Link succeeded, remove old name
        unlink($filename);
        return true;
    } else {
        // Link failed; filesystem has not been altered
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this will **not** work on Windows.