# Copy folder without overwriting

Tags: php

I found this question (here) about copying a **file** without overwriting

[How do you copy a file in PHP without overwriting an existing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226894/how-do-you-copy-a-file-in-php-without-overwriting-an-existing-file)

What I need is a php script to copy all files in a **folder**, there are also some subfolders; so it should be recursive.

I need to transfer it via FTP so I don't know this makes a big difference to the approach.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can I ask what it is that requires this to be a script written in PHP. It seems that using rsync would give you a lot better mileage for the effort involved.

Comment: I need to copy SQL server database files (.bak, etc), so pretty big files. The server I'm running the script on, as the source server where the files are on as the destination server are Linux Servers.
I was thinking about php because all other scripts are in PHP but other suggestions are welcome. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Try this, from [a comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#91010) on the manual page for [`copy`](http://www.php.net/copy):

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
```

Note that this solution will happily overwrite any files that exist in the `$dst` directory. If you want to avoid that, you could wrap the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226894/how-do-you-copy-a-file-in-php-without-overwriting-an-existing-file) into a function, and call that function instead of `copy`.

I'm not sure what you want to transfer via FTP, if you clarify that I'll be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: Very kind, thx for the reply. Will this solution work for FTP?
I want to transfer a few folders with SQL database files (pretty big files...).
I would run the script on a different server then the server where the databases are on. And the destination is another server.
Overwriting should be totally avoided as the files are so big.
THanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment - sorry if I'm being dense. If you want to fetch the files from the remote folder, then you need to do a bit more work (see `ftp_get` and `ftp_nlist`); if you want to put the files on a remote server (so you're running the backup process from the source server) then see `ftp_put`. But Ed's right - PHP is definitely not the tool for this job.

Comment: My bad. Apparently I need to look for a bash solution (?)

Comment: That's probably a better idea than PHP!

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between filesystem copy and FTP copy you could take a look at the [PEAR FTP Class](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_FTP/)